# Display a button when I tap a long list selector

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I want to display a button, when I tap a long list selector in windows phone 8.

C#

```
    this.DisplayedContacts = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        this.DataContext = this.DisplayedContacts;

        var contacts = new Contacts();

        contacts.SearchCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            foreach (var contact in e.Results)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(contact.PhoneNumbers.Any()? contact.PhoneNumbers.First().PhoneNumber: string.Empty);
                this.DisplayedContacts.Add(contact.DisplayName + " - " +
                (contact.PhoneNumbers.Any()
                    ? contact.PhoneNumbers.First().PhoneNumber
                    : string.Empty));
            }
        };

        contacts.SearchAsync(string.Empty, FilterKind.DisplayName, null);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> DisplayedContacts { get; set; }

    private void LongListSelector_Tap_1(object sender,GestureEventArgs e)
    {}
```

xaml code

```xaml
<phone:LongListSelector FontSize="50" Foreground="Gray" Tap="LongListSelector_Tap_1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,77,0,0" />
```

Comment: are you using MVVM Light ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `Visibility` property to hide your list and show the `Button`.
Your `XAML` will look something like bellow:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" >
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="LongList" Tap="LongListTap"/>
            <Button x:Name="ActionButton" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
```

And event handler:

```
 private void LongListTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            LongList.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ActionButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have to this just set the visibilty of your button to visible like suppose your buttn name is "Mybutton" ..

```
private void LongListSelector_Tap_1(object sender,GestureEventArgs e)
{
  Mybutton.Visibility = Visibility.visible;
}
```